# Necessary conditions for transforming a system of O.D.Es to a single O.D.E.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Considering the system:

$$u' = a(x)u + b(x)v$$
$$v' = c(x)u + d(x)v$$

I transform it to the second order O.D.E.(please check me on this because I might have mistakes):

$$\displaystyle u'' - \left (\frac{b'(x)}{b(x)} + a(x) + b(x) \right )u' + \left ( \frac{a(x)b'(x)}{b(x)} - a'(x) - c(x)b(x) + a(x)d(x) \right )u = 0$$

In the process, I am allowed to assuming as much differentiability as I want (on every function). Are there any other necessary conditions on the coefficients $a, b, c, d$ to do the above transformation?

Answer (score 1):

$v=(u'-au)/b$,

$v'=(-b'(u'-au)+b(u''-a'u-au'))/b^2=cu+d(u'-au)/b$,

$-b'u'+ab'u+bu''-a'bu-abu'=b^2cu+bdu'-abdu$,

$bu''-(bd+b'+ab)u'+(-b^2c+abd+ab'-a'b)u=0$

which is almost what you have --- I have a $du'$ where you have $bu'$.

The way you have written it, you need to worry about the possibility that $b(x)=0$ for some $x$ in the domain.

Comment: If I multiply everything by $b(x)$ will that resolve this problem? Would there be any others?

Comment: I don't see any other problems.

Comment: Τhanks a lot! Especially for catching the little mistake!